# How do I clear the Java cache on Mac OS 10.5.8?

Tags: mac, java

How do I clear the Java cache on Mac OS 10.5.8?

I'm not sure if this is browser-dependent, or just one thing for the full OS...

I found a help file that told me to go to 'Java Preferences' and click 'Delete Files'. But there's no 'Delete Files' button on my machine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In /Applications /Utilities /**Java Preferences** there is a Delete Temporary Files button in one of the tabs (it varies depending on which Java Version).